# read incoming Message packets in pubsub using smack

Tags: android, publish-subscribe, openfire, smack, asmack

i am trying to implement pubsub using `openfire` server and `asmack` library. 
i have configured my node in such a way that `subscribers` has to take the approval of `publishers`

now i am trying to read the `Message` packet using following code but i am not getting any packet. i want to read `Message` packet  because i want to know whenever the subscribers send the request to publishers to get subscribe.

```
PacketTypeFilter filter = new  PacketTypeFilter(org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message.class);

    PacketListener myListener = new PacketListener(){

        @Override
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.d("PACKET" , "READ");

            if(packet instanceof org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message){

                    org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message msg = (org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message) packet;

            Log.d("MY MESSAGE" , msg.toXML()+ "");


                    }
                }

            };

    cxmpp.addPacketListener(myListener, filter);
```

All i want is to read the incoming Message Packets

Answer (score 1):

If you have all the configuration bits and your pubsub component correctly working, then for getting a normal message you would do something like:

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("ADDRESS",PORT); // service name, also known as XMPP domain of the target server. 
config.setServiceName(this.pubsubServiceAddress);
connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
connection.connect();

PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.normal); 

connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() { 
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
    Message mes = (Message)packet;
        // do your stuff here
    }
}, filter);
```